# RecyclerView content height

Tags: android, height, android-recyclerview

Is there any good way of getting the height of the content inside RecyclerView? Considering all items may have different height.

In my scenario I'm using a LinearLayoutManager.

I've searched around and found surprisingly few results for this problem.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

RecyclerView is a `ViewGroup`. You can use `getChildAt` / `getChildCount` to get views. Then from the view, you can call `getWidth` / `getHeight`.

If you have ItemDecorators and need to get size including them, you can use `LayoutManager`'s `getDecorated<xxx>` methods.

Comment: Considering the nature of the RECYCLERView, won't that just get the child views that are actually created? Say I have a 100 items, maybe only 10 views are inflated and recycled.

Comment: If you are trying to get height of items that are not laid out, you cannot because they are not laid out. There cannot be a solution for this besides laying out every single item, which defeats the purpose of using RecyclerView.

Comment: But the RecylerView knows enough to layout the scrollbars correctly, so it must know something about it's contents height?

Comment: It approximates the total size of all items by taking the average size of current views multiplied by the number of items in the adapter.

Answer (score 52):

`RecyclerView.computeVerticalScrollRange` will give an estimation - it averages the height of the rows being currently displayed and multiplies that by the result of `getItemCount`

`computeHorizontalScrollRange` for width if you're orientation is horizontal.

Comment: this method always return 0

Answer (score 5):

I use to experiment with View.measure method:

```
recycler.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(recycler.width, View.MeasureSpec.EXACTLY), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED)
val height = recycler.measuredHeight
```

If your items are simple enough (e.g. with fixed heights), it should work.